# Synchronous property in datepicker component

Tags: javascript, angular

I am declaring a new object of `IMyDpOptions` and have a trouble with `markDates` property.
I'd like to load dates from database and can't figure out any solution to achieve this.
Always data come too late. I tried to return it as an Observable from my function `getDays()`, but this property does not accept Observable.

```
public myDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
markDates: this.getDays() || []
};

getDays() : Array<IMyMarkedDates>
{
    let obj: Array<IMyMarkedDates> = new Array<IMyMarkedDates>();
    obj[0] = <IMyMarkedDates>{};
    obj[0].color = '#ff0000';
    obj[0].dates = [];


        this._dataService.getJson('api/getDays')
            .subscribe(s => {
                this.daysOff = s;
                obj[0].dates = s || [];    
                return obj;
            });


}
```

How to properly do this? Is any way to wait for an observable request and return it synchronously?

Here is link to datpicker I used:
https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker

Comment: What do you mean by "data come too late"?

Comment: I mean that component is rendered without data from database, because the request takes too long.